Compare all the columns in a pandas dataframe with the values in two other columns and change the original value
I have a panda dataframe that looks something like this but with many more columns :



A
B
C
D




1
2
2
4


2
3
3
5



I now want to compare columns A and B to the values in C and D and get a dataframe that looks like this:



A
B
C
D




smaller
between
1
4


smaller
between
3
5



The rule is that considering row by row, a cell gets populated with “smaller” if its value is smaller than C, “between” if its value is between C and D and bigger if it is bigger than D.
The solution needs to be generalised for all the n columns that the original dataset can have once compared with C and D.
I am struggling to implement this in python.

Your output seems incorrect, 1 and 2 are both between 1-4

You could use np.select with two masks generated with gt/lt:
# using a defined list of columns
cols = ['A', 'B']

# or using all columns but C/D
cols = df.columns.difference(['C', 'D'])

tmp = df[cols]

df[cols] = np.select([tmp.gt(df['D'], axis=0),
                      tmp.lt(df['C'], axis=0)],
                     ['bigger', 'smaller'], 'between')

Output:
         A        B  C  D
0  smaller  between  2  4
1  smaller  between  3  5


What if I want a more generalised solution with not only A and B but with n other columns?

you can use as many columns as you want, provide a list (see update). If you want to use all columns but C/D, then cols = df.columns.difference(['C', 'D'])

@kyara you're welcome, if you're happy with the answer you can consider accepting it

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2],
    'B': [2, 3],
    'C': [2, 3],
    'D': [4, 5]
})

def categorize_column(col, C, D):
    """Categorize the values in a column based on comparison with C and D."""
    aa = np.select(
        [col < C , (col <= C) & (col < D), col < D ], ['smaller','between','bigger']
        )
    return aa

df['A'] = categorize_column(df['A'], df['C'], df['D'])
df['B'] = categorize_column(df['B'], df['C'], df['D'])

print(df)
'''
         A        B  C  D
0  smaller  between  2  4
1  smaller  between  3  5
'''

